# how fix "this certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority"

Tags: security, internet-explorer, certificate

I have problem in IE9 with securiry certificate.

Then I go to specific address I got

```
There is a problem with this website's security certificate.
```

How can I avoid appearence of this window?

I try enter on Continue to this website (not recommended). - cectificate error - View Certificates.
I see that This certificate is OK. in certificate Status on certification Path tab. But on the tab General I see text: `This certificate cannot be verified up to a trusted certification authority`
1) Install certificate
2) Export to my folder from mmc
3)go to  Tool - Internet option - Content - Certificates - Import, and import this sertificate to Trusted Root Certification Authorities, restart IE, but this certificate doesn't appears in this list.
I try to import it to Trusted Publishers - certificate appears in that list.
4) I check mmc, here this certificate is in section Trusted Root Certification Authorities.

After all those tries I still `There is a problem with this website's security certificate.` appears after I enter site url. Could someone help me to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Not all certificates can be installed as intermediate or root (they're limited by their "Basic Constraints" which you can see in View Certificate window on the Details tab).

Sounds to me like the certificate itself is good, but isn't trusted for one of the following reasons:

1. It was signed by a certificate authority that is not trusted, or the chain of trust is broken by some certificate that isn't trusted
2. The root authority certificate or one of the intermediate certificates is not installed in the browser's certificate store
3. One of the certificates in the chain of trust has expired
4. One of the certificates in the chain of trust is on a black list (CRL)

Take a look at the Certification Path tab and ensure all of the certificates are OK.  If they're bad they should have a red X.  Also, you can click on each node in the certification path to view the certificate at each level; visually inspect each one and ensure they are OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue on Windows and the fix was to **stop** the `Cisco AnyConnect Umbrella Roaming Security Agent` in Windows Services.  This was for a cert from the *Cisco Umbrella Root* in the *Certification Path* tab.